# Invalidated Prayer

Tags: salat, forgiveness

I was praying Asr and I had already done Salam and I was at the part where you pray and do dua. I burped and said “excuse me” is my prayer invalid?
Read

Comment: Ssalah finishes at salam. Anything you do after that will not effect the validity of your salah.

Answer (score 2):

You can hardly invalidate a prayer which has ended.

And the prayer ends with the salam or tasleem:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: The key of prayer is purification; takbir (saying "Allah is most great") makes (all acts which break prayer) unlawful and taslim (uttering the salutation) makes (all such acts) lawful.
> (See for example in Sunan abi Dawod [1](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/228) & [2](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:618), Sunan ibn Majah [1](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:276) & [2](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:276), [Musnad Ahmad](https://sunnah.com/ahmad:1006) and Jami' at-Tirmidhi [1](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:276) & [2](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:238))

Tahleel تحليل or making it lawful means, accomplishing it (and earning the rewards). So anything you've done after this has no impact on the prayer.  But one should consider repenting.